# Static pointer to member array for safe operator[] access

Tags: c++, boost, function-pointers, declaration

I was looking at the source code of boost::gil and I came across this comment and corresponding code in the 2D point class.

```
const T& operator[](std::size_t i)          const   { return this->*mem_array[i]; }
      T& operator[](std::size_t i)                  { return this->*mem_array[i]; }

...
private:
// this static array of pointers to member variables makes operator[]
// safe and doesn't seem to exhibit any performance penalty
static T point2<T>::* const mem_array[num_dimensions];
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/boost/gil/utilities.hpp

Questions:

1. What does this do exactly?
2. How does this make `operator[]` safe?

Comment: Since the comment doesn't define "safe" it's impossible to say what it means or how it works. Of course, it's always possible to **guess** at what it's intended to do, and spin hypotheses about how it might or might not do whatever that guess implies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the array is relevant – it is

```
template <typename T>
T point2<T>::* const point2<T>::mem_array[point2<T>::num_dimensions] 
    = { &point2<T>::x, &point2<T>::y };
```

The indirection through a pointer-to-member makes it possible to access the `x` coordinate of a point `p` as either  `p.x` or `p[0]`, and similarly for `p.y` and `p[1]`.

This is otherwise sometimes accomplished through (probably undefined) pointer trickery or a (possibly less efficient) branch on the index.

It is of course not absolutely safe since there is no bounds-checking, but it's safe in the sense of being standards-compliant and well-defined.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the right answer. I'm not sure if the word "safe" is the best word for what was accomplished here. Pretty nifty though.